# Unity inspector unable to save text script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to edit existing project in unity version 2017.1.3f1 my goal is to change the value of a text script using direct edit from the inspector. However everytime i save the project and run the application the change i have made is not reflecting. Can any one advice me on how to deal with this.

The methods that i have tried

1. Click the gear icon to load the csharp script but always showing error code
   "`Unable to open C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/GUISystem/Standalone/UnityEngine.UI.dll: Check external application preferences.`
2. I have change editor from MONO and Visual Studio but still no luck.

i have attached here some images that can help understand my concern.
RED circle is for the text wanted to change and the gear icon is suppose to leas the code but showing error as mention above

[image] [image]

Comment: You tagged this `Visual Studio` but your external editor settings clearly say `Mono Develop` .... so have you tried to switch this to `Visual Studio`? Also: You wouldn't try to edit the `Text` component source code ^^ You would rather implement your own script for applying the `GetComponent<Text>().text = "...";`

Comment: Hi as mention above i have switch both editor and unfortunately not successful.. do you have sample syntax or point me to the correct documentation on how to use GetComponent thanks

Comment: Removed `visual-studio` tag since this question is not about the IDE.

Comment: The **Text** component shown is the one created by Unity and part of the core application.  You can't edit the script in the same way you would a normal user script.  https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Text.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using Unity, and therefore the component system. The text is part of the old (deprecated) set of GUI components.
The editor window only allows you to cache the text that will be displayed. In order to load/change text, you need to create a C# script. C# script is added by pressing the AddComponent button, for example. Next, you need to use the Using UnityEngine.UI directive for your component, or TMPro for the Text Mesh Pro component.
If your changes don't show up, it's likely that the project has a system that loads certain texts into your text field. In this case, you need to find out which script is responsible for this.